# How can i set flyspell to Italian

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

still have some problem to configure emacs:

I use orgmode to write principally in italian, but also in english. So i want to use flyspell to check either language. I google and i find this [blog](http://manuel-uberti.github.io/emacs/2016/06/06/spellchecksetup/). After i launch `brew install hunspell`, downloaded the dictionary files and run `hunspell -D`, i modify my configuration.org file like this:

EDIT: i rewrite the code to include `ispell-dictionary-alist`

```
Enable spell-checking in Org-mode.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
#+END_SRC

setting flyspell in all my language by using hunspell

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
 (require 'ispell)
 (setq-default ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell")
           ispell-dictionary "it_IT")
 (setq ispell-dictionary-alist
 (append '(("italian"
      "[AÀÁB-EÈÉF-IÌÍJ-OÒÓP-UÙÚV-Zaàáb-eèéf-iìíj-oòóp-uùúv-z]"
      "[^AÀÁB-EÈÉF-IÌÍJ-OÒÓP-UÙÚV-Zaàáb-eèéf-iìíj-oòóp-uùúv-z]"
      "[---']" t nil "~iso" iso-latin-1)
 ("english"
      "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "[']" nil
      ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8))
 ispell-dictionary-alist))
 (setq ispell-menu-map nil)
 (load-library "ispell")
 (eval-after-load "ispell"
 (progn
 (setq ispell-dictionary "english"
      ispell-extra-args '("-a" "-i" "utf-8")
      ispell-silently-savep t)))

    (bind-key "C-c ì"
            (lambda ()
              (interactive)
              (ispell-change-dictionary "it_IT")
              (flyspell-buffer)))

  (bind-key "C-c è"
            (lambda ()
              (interactive)
              (ispell-change-dictionary "en_GB")
              (flyspell-buffer)))
#+END_SRC
```

But when i start emacs doesn't work flyspell, if i tipe `C-c ì` it say `wrong type argument:stringp,nil` and if i type `C-c è` it return `Undefined dictionary: en_GB`. Guesses?

EDIT: now the bind work, also code compile correctly, but when i change dictionary emacs say `Undefine dictionary: yada_YADA` with each of two dictionaries.

Comment: The code looks good so far. Maybe, you bind `C-c i` to some other command later on in your config file. Find the real binding with `C-h k C-c i`. Furthermore, it looks like you don't have `en_GB` in your `ispell-dictionary-alist`.

Comment: To not interfire with other function i use accented letter (easi to entry in italian layout). Thankyou for the command `C-h k` it will be very usefull. The shorcut are very usefull. The binds return the function i define above.  
Did i need to include `ispell-dictionary-alist` even if i use hunspell?